# How to get MAC address of Android device?

Tags: android

As you see, I want to get MAC address of an Android phone. But I always get null. I want to know how to get it.

Thanks a lot.

I used Android api to get Mac address, it returned 00:00:00:00:... I couldn't got the right value in high android api level device.